# Assigning Values to Variables Within Structs Through Pointers in C

Tags: c, algorithm, struct

Ok so I'm sure there's a simple fix that I'm missing, but right now my code is causing a segment fault on the line "A[i]->key = 0;." The Record* Item part is a necessity for the program, so I need to make it work this way for an assignment I'm working on, however if I do change it so that Item becomes a non-pointer typedef of Record, then I can use A[i].key no problem. I just need a nudge in the right direction so that I can make standInput correctly assign values to an array of pointers to records. Thanks!

Item.h:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef int keyType;

struct Record
{
    keyType key;
    int other;
};
typedef struct Record* Item;

void standInput(Item *A, int n)
{
    int i, input;
    for(i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        A[i]->key = 0;
        printf("%d ", A[i]->key);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "Item.h"

int main()
{
    int n;
    Item *A;
    printf("Enter a length for the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    A = (Item*)malloc(n * sizeof(Item));
    standInput(A, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure A is of `Item*` and not just `Item` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in `A` are all uninitialized, but you're using them as `struct Record` pointers anyway. If you want to have `A` continue holding pointers (rather than the structs directly), then you need to allocate space for `A` *and* for each item pointed to by `A`.

Comment: Hobbs: Thank you! I would never have gotten that, but it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `Item` is already a pointer!

You have to allocate space for the struct, not for the pointer:

```
A = (Item)malloc(n * sizeof(struct Record));
```

Note: If the typedef for pointer confuses you, don't use it ;)

`A[i]->key` means that `A[i]` is a pointer, but you just allocated an array, so use `A[i].key`.

Note: you have to change the type of A accordingly.

**2nd solution:** if you want A[i] to be a pointer, you have to fist allocate space for the pointers (as you do now), then for each pointer (in a loop) allocate space for the struct.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a problem; the standInput function accept a Item pointer and A is declared as Item*. Am i wrong?

Comment: It depends on how you want to tackle the problem. A continuous array of elements or an array of pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Your structure name is `Record` not `Item`. So you should use `sizeof(struct Record)`.

Comment: Thanks, I switched it out to use sizeof(struct Record), but it's still giving me the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you want your code to do. Are you creating an array of "Item"?

Comment: Yeah the assignment asked for an array of Items that are pointers to structs Record. Honestly I'm still a little confused by it as well since the instructors communication skills aren't the greatest, but I've been piecing it together from Robert Sedgewick's book Algorithms in C.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    Item *A;
    printf("Enter a length for the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    A = (Item*)malloc(n * sizeof(Item));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        A[i] = (Item)malloc(sizeof(struct Record));
    }
    standInput(A, n);
    return 0;
}
```